# `multiprocessing.pool.starmap()` works wrong when I want to write my custom vector env for DRL

Tags: python, multiprocessing, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I try to write a customized vectorized environment for DRL algorithm so I can monitor some information I concern.

I initialize the multiprocessing pool when the class `CustomVectorEnv` is initialized, with the same num of environment number.

However, I met a bug. when I call function `step_wrapper`, everything seems normal, the environment interacts correctly with my algorithm, but when the code `results = self.pool.starmap(step_wrapper, zip(self.envs, self._actions))` finishes in function `step`, all environments become the same as when it was initialized, and the states are not updated.

I have checked that function `reset` has never been called, no new environments are created, just the environments initialized along with class `CustomVectorEnv`, and the environments are just refreshed after the line of code I mentioned but normall within the function `stp_wrapper`.

What may be the problem?
I would appreciate it if you could provide me any imformation.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import gymnasium as gym
import numpy as np
from gymnasium.vector.utils import concatenate, create_empty_array, iterate
from gymnasium.vector.vector_env import VectorEnv

def step_wrapper(env, action):
    results = env.step(action.cpu())
    return results

def make_env_single(env_id, idx, render_mode=None, FD=None):
    env = gym.make(env_id, render_mode=render_mode, FD=FD)
    env = gym.wrappers.FlattenObservation(env)  # deal with dm_control's Dict observation space
    env = gym.wrappers.RecordEpisodeStatistics(env)
    env = gym.wrappers.ClipAction(env)

    return env

class CustomVectorEnv(VectorEnv):
    def __init__(
            self,
            env_id, capture_video, run_name, gamma, num_envs=1,
            observation_space: Space = None,
            action_space: Space = None,
            copy: bool = True,
    ):
        self.envs = [make_env_single(env_id, i) for i in range(num_envs)]
        ...

        self.pool = mp.Pool(processes=self.num_envs)

    def step(self, actions):
        self._actions = iterate(self.action_space, actions)
        observations, rewards, terminateds, truncateds, infos = [], [], [], [], {}

        #the line where error occurs
        results = self.pool.starmap(step_wrapper, zip(self.envs, self._actions))
        
        ...
```